# Bootstrap navbar toggle button is not functioning

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

When the page is reduced to tablet/mobile size, the toggle button is displayed but does not work.  Here is the html

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">

  <div class="container">
   <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-nav-demo" aria-expanded="false">
     <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a href="#" class="navbar-brand"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-picture" aria-hidden="true"></span> IMGS</a>
   </div>
   <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-nav-demo">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
     <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
     <li><a href="#">Sign Up</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
  </div>

 </nav>

....
....


 <script type="text/javascript" href="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.1.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

It does include the required js links.

Comment: stupid question but : your opening <nav> isn't pasted here on purpose ?

Comment: That was a mistake in editing the code block.  It is adjusted

Comment: I checked all similar questions, but I can't find the solution.  Maybe something small needs to be corrected

Answer (score 1):

So I found the issue; it is very slight.  The href attribute should be replaced with a src attribute on script tags.  Sublime Text's tab press for script defaults an href.

```html
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.1.js"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```